# How to put Attachment indicator in ios7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to replace the accessory type -which mentioned here-

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

with that attachment indicator, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is known as `accessoryView` a property of `UITableViewCell`

**accessoryView**

A view that is used, typically as a control, on the right side of the cell (normal state).

**@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView**

**Discussion**
If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal (default) state; it ignores the value of the accessoryType property. The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or label or a custom view. The accessory view appears in the right side of the cell.

so set it like this

```
[cell setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attachmentImage"]]];
```

if you want you can set your `UIVIew` instead of `UIImageView`